# How can you retrieve the IP address from an open TCPConn*?

Tags: go

I have a TCPConn* that I've accepted from a TCPListener.acceptTCP.  I'd like to get only the IP address (no port information) as a string or IP.  What is the correct (i.e. minimal casting/string manipulation) way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the IP, as an IP object, the most straightforward way should be

```
tcpconn.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr).IP
```

There is nothing wrong with using type assertions, and in cases like this it's actually expected.

Comment: http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.RemoteAddr in the function description explicitly states a `*net.TCPAddr` is returned. This is an open invitation to type assert.